# Check Barcode valid from phonegab android to remote phpfile

Tags: php, android, cordova, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I can read Qrcode and what i want is to check if the text in qrcode is in remote database. I have a php file where I do some process to check if database is in mysql. But it does not work. below my code

```
/*part of js file

scan: function() {
    console.log('scanning');

    var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");

    scanner.scan( function (result) { 

        var rs= result;
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            data: rs,

            url: 'http://url/page.php',

            success: function(data){

            console.log(data);

            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = data;

        },

        error: function(){

        console.log(data);

        alert('error');

    }

});



return false;


    }, function (error) { 
        console.log("Scanning failed: ", error); 
    } );
}
```

/* My php file

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn =  mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db("database", $conn);
$result=$_POST['result'] ;  //value from qrcode scanned by device
$sql="SELECT * FROM tabe WHERE code = '$result' ";

$rs = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$count=mysql_num_rows($rs);

if($count == 1) {
echo "ok";
}
else
{
return "No Ok";
}

?>
```

Comment: so , how many rows do your have in "database" that match the QR code ? obcit: read about SQL injection, and switch to PDO **[see little bobby's fairy tale](http://bobby-tables.com)**. Also, mysql_ functions are deprecated, hurry before your PHP does not support it anymore.

Comment: Thank @YvesLeBorg. I have use old function in php just for test. I have only one row that match the Qrcode. My php file work but i can get value from php in my app after ajax call.